# stripping text from beginning/end of an variable

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array containing a list of backup files, I want to go through and strip off the leading /path/to/file/ and the trailing _date_stamp.tar.gz My code works to strip off the leading pathtofile and if I set it to just strip off the .tar.gz it works, but if I try to strip the date it fails. So as an example I want to take:

```
/path/to/file/backup_domain1.com_02_16_2015.tar.gz
```

and be left with:

```
domain1.com
```

This removed from start: `/path/to/file/backup_`
This removed from end: `_02_16_2015.tar.gz` but obviously as they are date stamped then the integers will vary.

My code snippet:

```
# strip leading path/to/file :
$bubasedir=/path/to/file
buarray=( "${buarray[@]#"$bubasedir/backup_"}" )
buarray=( "${buarray[@]%".tar.gz"}" )
```

This strips `.tar.gz` but I need to strip the date as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an expression which matches the date expression, just like you do for the prefix.  Assuming the domain name cannot contain an underscore (as per the DNS spec, but sometimes violated for internal domains and special domains like `_dkim`),

```
buarray=( "${buarray[@]%%_*}" )
```

`%%` says to trim the longest possible match and `_*` matches everything starting from an underscore.  (`"${buarray[@]%_*}"` would trim from the last underscore.)

Comment: Thanks, should have pasted my non-working code which was:

  buarray=( "${buarray[@]%%"_*"}" )

Obviously my needless double quotes was killing it